# Restore grub - possibility of using Gparted Live

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've just installed Windows 7 after installation of Ubuntu 13.10. Can I use Gparted Live CD to restore GRUB? I ask, because my Internet connection is very slow and Gparted Live is small (150 MB).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure how lightweight Gparted's liveCD is.

Install MBR from liveCD/DVD/USB, Ubuntu install on sda5 and want grub2's bootloader in drive sda's MBR:
Find linux partition, change sda5 if not correct:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

confirm that linux is sda5

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

The above command should work but they now suggest this command for grub 1.99 with Natty 11.04 or later - uses boot not root.:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

If that returns any errors run:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

If no errors on previous commands reboot into working system and run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I unusually suggest Boot-Repair but do not know if it runs or not (it does work in several distributions) as it needs some standard utilities. It is not a huge download (mostly bash script) and does have a Lubuntu based version to download.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I noticed, that in Gparted Live CD, there isin't chroot, so I must download Ubuntu Live CD ;(

Comment: Thanks! I had Kali installed and after installing Windows i could no longer boot into Kali. I booted into a gparted live usb i had lying around, and ran the commands. Now i can boot into Kali again, and Windows.

Comment: These commands worked like a charm. I used gparted live cd to resize my root partition and had to fix my boot loader afterwards.